# How does STM32 pin assigment work in cubeMX?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I'm configuring a stm32 chip in cubeMX (a code configurator). The specific chip is the STM32H7A3ZITQ.

When you enable a peripheral, the io pins for that peripheral are highlighted in green on the chip diagram. Usually, there is also a peripheral setting that allows you to choose from multiple pin assignments for one signal.

Makes sense so far.

BUT, it seems like sometimes when I enable 2 peripherals and there is a conflict, some pin assignments can shift to new pins, which I wasn't aware were available. Is that's what's happening?

To pose the question from another angle. Lets say I'm configuring the OCTO-SPI port Data[3:0] pins. How can I view all possible assignments for those pins? Is it just the 2 options in the dropdown list? or are there more choices?

Answer (score 1):

It reads in the manual. Click with ALT or SHIFT or CTRL or whatever keys you might have and then click the pin and it will show other possibilities for that alternate functionality.

You can also search the datasheet to find all pins with e.g. SPI1_SCK feature.